# autocmd with quickfix window

Tags: autocmd, quickfix

How can set BufEnter or WinEnter autocmds for entering quickfix window?

I tried

```
autocmd WinEnter quickfix echo 'winenter'
autocmd BufEnter quickfix echo 'bufenter'
```

None of them works. I doubt that it is because these two commands needs file name after the event name. Then what is the file pattern for quickfix window?

I have fugitive installed. By filling the quickfix window using `Glog`, the statusline for the quickfix window shows something like `[:git --git-dir=...] [Quickfix List]`. Is this the filename of the quickfix buffer which should be used in the pattern of the `BufEnter/WinEnter` event?

I cannot see anything if I `echo @%` which should usually show the current bufname.

Comment: `autocmd Filetype qf ...` may work as well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The parameter for both the `WinEnter` and `BufEnter` events are matched against the buffer *name*, which is empty for the quickfix window:

```
:echo bufname('')
[no output]
```

You can still use the `buftype` variable though:

```
autocmd WinEnter * if &buftype == 'quickfix' | echo 'winenter' | endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't always work for me. See below answer by Kirill Bugaev.

Answer (score 9):

Just a remark to Martin Tournoij answer.

When you just opened a quickfix buffer/window (and not switched to it yet), the `&buftype` option is not set yet. You may find another autocommand event useful:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter quickfix echo 'bufwinenter'
```