# Set cursor in quickfix on autocmd event

Tags: vimscript

I need to set cursor position when *opening* quickfix window. I have tried

```
autocmd BufEnter * call cursor(2, 2)
```

It doesn't set cursor for quickfix buffer immediately after I have opened it.

UPD: I am trying to save current cursor position of quickfix window when close it and restore when open again.

```
let s:saved_cursor = [0, 1, 1]
autocmd BufDelete * call s:SaveCursor()
autocmd BufWinEnter quickfix call s:RestoreCursor()

func s:SaveCursor()
    if expand("<abuf>") == s:get_qf_bufnr()
        let s:saved_cursor = getpos('.')
    endif
endfunc

func s:RestoreCursor()
    call cursor(s:saved_cursor[1], s:saved_cursor[2])
endfunc

func s:get_qf_bufnr()
    for buf_i in getbufinfo()
        if getbufvar(buf_i.bufnr, '&buftype') == 'quickfix'
            return buf_i.bufnr
        endif
    endfor
    return -1
endfunc
```

It doesn't work.
Scenario is below:

1) Open and fill quickfix buffer by `cs find` command

2) Move cursor in quickfix window

3) Close quickfix window by `:cclose` (and save cursor position by `s:SaveCursor()` function)

4) Open quickfix again by `:copen` (and restore cursor position by `s:RestoreCursor()` function)

Probably `BufWinEnter autocmd` event is not suitable for my purpose and I am trying to set cursor before quickfix window opened.
On `BufEnter` event I can set cursor position if quickfix window is already opened. But if I close quickfix window and open it again cursor will be at first line first column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [autocmd with quickfix window](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14065/autocmd-with-quickfix-window)

Comment: So, you want to set the cursor position in a quickfix list? From where? I mean, are you writing a script? If so, then do you assume the quickfix window is already open? I originally thought you just wanted to open the quickfix window after a quickfix command. Provide a detailed scenario, cause your question doesn't really makes sense to me.

Comment: I have added some details in question.

Comment: Have you checked, that `s:SaveCursor()` called?

Comment: Ralf, thanks for replay. I checked `s:SaveCursor()` on `BufDelete` event, it works. But your `BufLeave` variant looks more logical.

Answer (score 1):

From the source code it looks like the position in the quickfix window is determined by the current position in the quickfix list. This is set after the window was opened, hence after your autocmd ran.

First you need the autocmd event `BufLeave`, to save the cursor position (the quickfix buffer is not deleted). Then change your function `s:RestoreCursor` to contain:

```
call cursor(g:saved_cursor[0], g:saved_cursor[1])
echom "My Pos: " . string(getpos('.'))
```

This should print the cursor position you want to restore. But in the end the cursor ends up on the line corresponding to the current position in the quickfix list.

I have no idea how to prevent this.

Comment: Now `s:RestoreCursor` shows cursor position and it is exactly which in `s:saved_cursor` variable. Cursor is really moved to current position in the quickfix list. Any way thanks a lot for explanation of how things work.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your vimrc

```
augroup quickfix
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* nested cwindow
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost    l* nested lwindow
augroup END
```

From `:h QuickFixCmdPost`, this autocommand event is triggered after a quickfix command is run. And `[^l]*` makes sure that the quickfix command is not actually a location list command. From `:h location-list`, a location list is a window-local quickfix list, and to create a location list window, you'll just have to put an `l` at the beginning of the equivalent quickfix command. So, depending on whether the command has `l` at the beginning, the quickfix or location-list window is opened.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I don't understand what this commands should do? I have putted it to my .vimrc, but I still can't set cursor in quickfix window by autocmd event when I open quickfix window.

Comment: As the OP suggests, an accompanying explanation could go a long way

Comment: I thought OP just wanted to open quickfix window after a quickfix command. I guess, s/he edited the question after I read. I don't know what s/he wants.